# Tower of boxes(angry birds)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, nested

The tower is created fine but for some reason only the bottom of the tower is been affected by birds all the boxes at the top remains static, when the birds come into contact with the tower only the bottom is been affected.

```
function setupTower(){

for(var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        noStroke();
        boxes.push(Bodies.rectangle(900 - j * 90, 540 - i * 90, 80, 80));
      
        colors.push(color(0, random(255), 0));
        
    }
    World.add(engine.world, [boxes[i]]);
}

function drawTower(){
push();

for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++){
    
    fill(colors[i]);
    drawVertices(boxes[i].vertices);
}
pop();

}
```